Are mental images of mathematical entities persistent?
Each individual mathematician has a mental image of a given mathematical entity or assertion (here the term mental image is used in a generic sense, not a technical sense).
Whether most of them have similar (or on the contrary dissimilar) mental images is an interesting issue.
Does the literature discuss the persistence of mental images as evidence in favor of Platonism; or the variability of mental images, as evidence in favor of Formalism?
This question is a follow-up to an exchange below this answer.

Even if our mental models of mathematical objects were exactly the same person to person (and this is doubtful), why would those objects be in the same realm if we all have different minds?

@Syed, This is a very good question but notice that my query concerns the existence of literature discussing such issues.  My personal opinion is that it would indeed be difficult to settle this "from first philosophical principles".

@Mauro, Could you please summarize how these could be relevant to the issue of persistency/variability of mental images/intuitions as applied to the platonism/formalism debate?

Platonism makes no assertions about how the human mind works, as such this question is psychological, not philosophical.

@tkruse, This question is a reference request.  Apparently an argument in favor of mathematical Platonism has been made based on the claim that mathematicians have the same mental image of a given mathematical entity or assertion, which suggests some kind of universality.  I am wondering what the sources for such discussions would be; or, in the opposite direction, whether it has been argued that mathematicians' mental images are in fact variable (which could perhaps  be interpreted as evidence against Platonism).

Can you explain more of what you mean by "mental image used in a generic sense"?

@gs, according to user David Guderman in his answer below, the term "mental model" is used in a specific technical sense.  So I changed "mental model" to "mental image", insisting that I am using the term in a generic (not technical) sense.  I could have also used "intuitive image", etc.

Are you referring to imaginary videos that we map to concepts as if they were visually seen symbols?

Hadamard queried mathematicians on their use of mental imagery, words and symbols in thinking, his description of the results is in ch. VI of The Psychology of Invention in the Mathematical Field. Apparently, uses vary widely in form and function, but images are deliberately fuzzy and rarely attach to individual entities.

Kant's CPR discussed constructive variability and persistence in detail via the most persistent intuition of time connecting inner sense for producing mental images built by subjective imagination thus rejecting psychologism to retain some platonic objectivity, instead of outer sense space intuition of geometers which Riemann also warned belongs to the department of physics. This is why non-platonic constructive arithmetic a la Heyting was strongly inspired by Kantian constructivism, while geometry especially non-Euclidean ones have little to do with Kantian space, if not conflict with it…

@DoubleKnot, you seemed to argue at the other question that the persistence of mental images of mathematical entities constitutes evidence in favor of mathematical Platonism.  Your comment motivated in part my question here.  There are currently three answers but none of them seem to provide any reference where such an argument in favor of Platonism would be made.  Do you have a source for such an argument?

By grounding the persistent time in the inner sense and view math as synthetic a priori, Kant avoids psychologism, the natural reduction of epistemology to psychology, by framing time as a necessary condition for cognition rather than as mental artifact. Mathematical entities persist as mental images because they are grounded in the temporal form of intuition, which allows us to construct and "hold" them in our cognition. See CPR A34/B50: Time is the formal a priori condition of all appearances whatsoever. platonism here is not to mean an independent realm but objective cognitive realism...

The view that mathematical objects are mental models is called psychologism. It is not a popular view of mathematics for several reasons. Perhaps the most pressing is that it implies that mathematicians are all talking about different numbers, namely the numbers in their own head, so there is no reason to think the laws would be the same for everyone. This is part of the motivation for mathematical realism, which is also known as platonism (with a small "p" to distinguish it from Platonism, the views of Plato). Mathematical realism claims that numbers are not mental objects; they are abstract objects which exist neither in the mind nor in nature. Abstract objects are atemporal and causally inert.
According to mathematical realism, the mental models of the mathematician are not relevant to mathematics. These mental models may serve to pick out the abstract objects that mathematicians discuss, but that is no different from the mental models of a physicist that pick out the physical objects he is talking about. For the physicist, the topic is not his mental model but the physical objects; for the mathematician, the topic is not his mental model but the abstract objects

Perhaps the term "mental models" was not well chosen, since it seems to have a technical meaning in a different context.  I think I will change it to "mental images".  The term is being used in its generic sense; every mathematician certainly has a mental image of whatever mathematical entities he is working with.  It seems to me that one can make such a statement without committing oneself to a particular philosophical position.  In other words, one can ask whether mathematician A has the same mental image of, say, the real numbers as mathematician B, without committing oneself to a position.

Two books that might be relevant:

Mathematical Epistemology and Psychology, by E.W.Beth and Jean Piaget
This is a remarkable book - product of the cooperation between a Dutch mathematician/logician/philosopher and a psychologist -- known for his study of the cognitive development of children. (Unfortunately my library is in near total disarray so I cannot find my copy and quote from this. But if anything this book should make Platonism less plausible.)
Intuition in Science and Mathematics - An Educational Approach, by Efraim Fischbein (1987)This is a classic study of intuition. It's not a philosophical essay and does not discuss Platonism/Intuitionism/Formalism or any metamathematical philosophical conundrums, but it is, imo, one of the most relevant studies for that discussion -- it could perhaps shed some light on the actual reasons why people believe in platonism or on what is actually valuable in platonist realism.

Looking for related articles on google scholar I also came across a reference to Potential space and mathematical reality by P. Maher (1994), quoted in Knowing more than we can tell by N. Sinclair (2009). In philosophical discussions it's usually only the purely cognitive aspects or "reasons" for/against platonism that are mentioned. But Maher makes some interesting observations/guesses about the emotional aspects of a Platonist belief in the "reality" of mathematical objects. Quote from Sinclair:

The notion of embracing a totality, or making whole, described by Poincaré surfaces time and time again in the admittedly small corpus of mathematicians writing about mathematics. Indeed, the mathematician Philip Maher (1994) offers an explanation for the ontogenesis of characteristically mathematical activity of making whole by drawing on Lacan’s notion of the mirror stage, which describes the transition state during which an infant comes to recognise her reflection in the mirror as being her own. At this point, the “infant sees a totality which he or she can control through his or her own movement”. (...)
Maher’s account proposes two other explanations of characteristically mathematical activity. One involves the use of psychoanalyst Donald Winnicott’s theory of transitional objects to explain the way in which mathematicians are attracted to the Platonic idea of mathematical reality. Nicolas Bouleau (2002) also draws on Winnicott to interpret the unconscious experience of the mathematician —- pleasure, desire and sublimation —- as being analogous to the experience of the child playing at a distance from his loving mother, being allowed to explore without fear, and being free to use the objects around him in symbolic ways: "The background of rigour on which the researcher’s scientific works depends plays a fundamental role that conditions every movement and every initiative. It is analogous to maternal love for the child: it is simultaneously a reference, a presence and a security."

Do mathematical objects have the "reality" of transitional objects -- between really "real" and merely fictional? Perhaps philosophy would be richer if it admitted this kind of intermediate transitional realities in its bleak binary ontologies? :)

You mentioned last time the essay “Bernays, Paul. Zum Symposium "Ueber die Grundlagen der Mathematik. Dialectica 25, no. 3/4,”
I stumbled on his remark on p. 177:

Zuzugeben ist, dass wir keine
eigentlich visuelle Vorstellung von unendlichen Gesamtheiten besitzen
; aber eine solche besitzen wir auch schon nicht von sehr
grosszahligen Gesamtheiten, obwohl doch solche nach unserer Erfahrung
in der Natur existieren. Die volle visuelle Vorstellbarkeit ist also
gar nicht massgebend fur unsere Behauptungen und Annahmen von
Existenz, auch im Sinne der Naturwirklichkeit. Andererseits gibt es
Arten eines repräsentativen Vorstellens, in welchem Begrifflichkeit
und Anschauung vermischt sind und dessen Reichweite schwer abzugrenzen
ist. Die Ansicht von der scharfen Trennung von Begriff und Anschauung
in unserem Geistesleben, wie sie insbesondere in der Kantischen
Philosophie behauptet wird, muss gewiss revidiert werden.

Bernays speaks about Begriff und Anschauung (concept and intuition). Unfortunately he does not give an example, e.g., taking the abstract concept of a group and a corresponding intuition.
Surely in mathematics there are some standard examples of intutition, e.g. the projective space P^2 as the compactified affine plane with three distinct lines {z_0=0}, {z_1=0}, {z_2=0} forming a triangle. I think we learn this kind of intuition during the corresponding lectures from our teacher, and then exercize how to use this visualization.

Should the phrase "I stumbled on his remark on p. 177" be outside the quotation?  So "intuition" is another term I could have used for "mental image".  The question concerns the literature on persistency or variability of such intuitions of a given mathematical entity, and whether or not this furnishes evidence in favor of this or that philosophy of mathematics.

I am not sure why you are adding three lines to form P^2.  It is obtained from the affine plane by adding a single line at infinity.  Perhaps you are thinking of the Fano plane (over the field with two elements) where one adds three points at infinity to form P^2.

@MikhailKatz I made the corrections; thanks.

Hmm.  If z0, z1, z2 are homogeneous coordinates and x=z1/z0 and y=z2/z0 are the affine coordinates, then adding the line z0=0 is enough to get the entire P^2.
